# Recibir un aviso cuando alguien deje un comentario en mi web

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli, pdo

Tengo este código, que es un formulario para dejar comentarios en mi web. Me gustaría saber si  hay alguna manera de conseguir que añadiendo algo más de código pueda llegarme un aviso a mi correo cuando alguien deje un comentario en la web. El código que os dejo funciona bien, no tiene fallos solo lo pongo para que veáis lo que estoy utilizando.Gracias por adelantado

```
       <div class="container">
   <form method="POST" id="comment_form">
<div class="form-group">
 <input type="text" name="comment_name" id="comment_name" class="form- 
  control" placeholder="Enter Name" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <textarea name="comment_content" id="comment_content" class="form-control" 
  placeholder="Enter Comment" rows="5"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" id="comment_id" value="0" />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" 
   value="Submit" />
</div>
```

```
 add_comment.php:



  <?php

//add_comment.php


  $connect = new PDO('mysql:host=);

   $error = '';
   $comment_name = '';
   $comment_content = '';

      if(empty($_POST["comment_name"]))
     {
     $error .= '<p class="text-danger">Name is required</p>';
    }
      else
    {
     $comment_name = $_POST["comment_name"];
      }

    if(empty($_POST["comment_content"]))
   {
    $error .= '<p class="text-danger">Comment is required</p>';
    }
    else
    {
     $comment_content = $_POST["comment_content"];
     }

     if($error == '')
    {
    $query = "
   INSERT INTO tbl_comment 
 (parent_comment_id, comment, comment_sender_name) 
 VALUES (:parent_comment_id, :comment, :comment_sender_name)
  ";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute(
  array(
   ':parent_comment_id' => $_POST["comment_id"],
   ':comment'    => $comment_content,
   ':comment_sender_name' => $comment_name
     )
    );
     $error = '<label class="text-success">Comment Added</label>';
     }

     $data = array(
 'error'  => $error
    );

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Comment: que tipo de aviso es el que deseas ?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask]. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta, colocando qué es lo que hace tu código, donde estas teniendo problemas y cual es el resultado esperado

Comment: Una pregunta sin cuerpo como la tuya lo que hace es retrasar la ayuda: obliga a quien quiere ayudarte a analizar todo tu código para tratar de adivinar 1. Lo que hace; 2. Dónde está el fallo. ¿Por qué no te tomas la molestia de explicar esos dos puntos con claridad ya que eres el interesado?

Comment: @A.Cedano  el código  funciona bien, es un formulario simple, solo preguntaba si hay alguna forma de añadir algo de código mas que de la orden cuando me dejan un comentario en la web que a mi me llegue un correo....por he puesto lo que tengo , siento no haberme expresado mejor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías mandar un correo de aviso mediante alguna función mail.

```
$destinatario = 'tucorreo@correo.com';
$asunto = 'Nuevo mensaje en tu web';
$mensaje = 'Mira el artículo x, tienes un mensaje nuevo de Pepito que dice: mensaje.';
$cabeceras = 'From: noresponder@correo.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: noresponder@correo.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($destinatario, $asunto, $mensaje, $cabeceras);
```

De todos modos es un ejemplo básico, deberías proteger variables, ver si tu servidor soporta el envío con la función mail, límites de envío, etc...

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda!! dónde debería poner este código? Al final del  archivo  add_comment.php:?

Comment: En tu caso, una vez verificado que la información se ha insertado en la base de datos.

Comment: Gracias! Voy a probar